# Snowflake/SQL: create a time-series table such that every ID is visible, and if ID is null, it uses the previous value? (similar to shift)

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Suppose I have the following table:

| Day | ID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-05 | 0 | A |
| 2022-11-06 | 1 | B |
| 2022-11-07 | 0 | C |

Now given a time window of 1 day, I want to create a time-series table that:

- The `Day` column granular unit is 1 day
- Each `Day` row displays every ID in the table (like cross-join)
- Moreover, if for that day, the ID is not recorded, then it uses the `Value` from the previous day. If it does not exist before this day, we can ignore it.

Let's say I want to view this time series from `2022-11-05` to `2022-11-08`, this is the desired output:

| Day | ID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-05 | 0 | A |
| **2022-11-06** | **0** | **A** |
| 2022-11-06 | 1 | B |
| 2022-11-07 | 0 | C |
| **2022-11-07** | **1** | **B** |
| **2022-11-08** | **0** | **C** |
| **2022-11-08** | **1** | **B** |

Explanation: `ID=0` is not recorded on 11-06 so it uses the value from the previous day. `ID=1` does not record new value on 11-07 so it uses the value from 11-06.

Note that the number of columns can be large, so if possible, I am looking for a solution that handles it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Way One:

- first we start with some `data`
- then we find `the_days` in the period we are interested in
- then we find the `data_start` for each id
- then we join those values together, and use `LAG` with the `IGNORE NULLS OVER` clause to find the "prior values" if the current values in not present via `NVL`

```
with data(Day, ID, Value) as (
    select * from values
        ('2022-11-05'::date, 0, 'A'),
        ('2022-11-06'::date, 1, 'B'),
        ('2022-11-07'::date, 0, 'C')
), the_days as (
    select 
        row_number() over (order by null)-1 as rn
        ,dateadd('day', rn, from_day) as day
    from (
        select 
            min(day) as from_day
            ,'2022-11-08' as to_day
            ,datediff('days', from_day, to_day) as days
        from data
    ), table(generator(ROWCOUNT => 200))
    qualify rn <= days
), data_starts as (
    select 
        id, 
        min(day) as start_day
    from data
    group by 1
)
select 
    td.day,
    ds.id,
    nvl(d.value, lag(d.value) ignore nulls over (partition by ds.id order by td.day)) as value
from data_starts as ds
join the_days as td 
    on td.day >= ds.start_day
left join data as d
    on ds.id = d.id and d.day = td.day
order by 1,2;
```

gives:

| DAY | ID | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-05 | 0 | A |
| 2022-11-06 | 0 | A |
| 2022-11-06 | 1 | B |
| 2022-11-07 | 0 | C |
| 2022-11-07 | 1 | B |
| 2022-11-08 | 0 | C |
| 2022-11-08 | 1 | B |

### Way Two:

```
with data(Day, ID, Value) as (
    select * from values
        ('2022-11-05'::date, 0, 'A'),
        ('2022-11-06'::date, 1, 'B'),
        ('2022-11-07'::date, 0, 'C')
), the_days as (
    select 
        dateadd('day', row_number() over (order by null)-1, '2022-11-05') as day
    from table(generator(ROWCOUNT => 4))
)
select 
    td.day,
    i.id,
    nvl(d.value, lag(d.value) ignore nulls over (partition by i.id order by td.day)) as _value
from the_days as td
cross join (select distinct id from data) as i
left join data as d
    on i.id = d.id and d.day = td.day
qualify _value is not null
order by 1,2;
```

this requires a unique name for the `_values` output so it can be referenced in the qualify without needing to duplicate the code.

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for, thanks! As a small extension, can it be generalized to tables where the number of columns grow very large?

Comment: We the start date, distinct id's part is all the same, and a LAG is a little expensive, but if you have N x LAG's imho that cost no extra. It's the Partitioning and the Ordering that is the cost (if they all have the same partition order logic that is)